# Sorting an associative array based on a particular element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

I have an associative array, but I want to sort order them by the 'cat_name

```
$test = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 5
            [cat_name] => Resolution
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 6
            [cat_name] => Speed
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 7
            [cat_name] => Accuracy 
        )
)
```

When I do sort($test), it sorts the array in order of 'cat_id', how do I sort it by 'cat_name'?

Comment: One way would be to add the 'cat_name' into the array before the 'cat_id', then it will just sort by the first associated element in the array.

Comment: We need to add to or edit this dupe or find a better one.  No `array_column()` in any of the answers.

Comment: @AbraCadaver why? no need to edit, deceze's answer (the first one) should suffice, it has the `usort` +  `strcmp` flavor. it should sort that by `cat_name`

Comment: if this came from the db, why not do the sorting there instead